# what is the difference between xx-large and larger in CSS?

Tags: css

I was reading about relative and absolute size in CSS and came across this question.

what's the difference between `xx-large` and `larger` other than absolute and relative? also what is meant by scaling factor?

**The larger seems to be smaller than xx-large in the browser. why?**

```css
.one{
    font-size:xx-large;
}
.two{
    font-size:larger;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>
  <h1 class="one">hello</h1>
  <h1 class="two">hello</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: XXL - extra extra large, sounds more impressive than just 'larger'

Comment: The answer you seek is clearly stated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size

Comment: @Martin Did you vote to close this as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"?

Comment: @Sean the question asked is clearly answered by the reference link to MDN. It takes a few seconds to find this answer, therefore this Q is not strictly a StackOverflow topic.

Comment: @Martin Questions that don't show research effort should be downvoted, not closed as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"

Comment: @Sean it doesn't show research effort, as stated -- the question can be answered in full within seconds and is clearly answered by a simple clear link as stated in my comment above. However, the request to close in this instance is not my request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes `larger` is bigger than `xx-large`, and sometimes the opposite is true. One is a relative size value and the other is an absolute size value. See the examples below for an illustration.

`larger` (not to be confused with `large`) is a *relative* size keyword, which will increase the size of the text one step from whatever it currently is.

`xx-large` is an *absolute* size keyword, which sets the size of the text to a specific size, regardless of what its current size is.

For more information, refer to [Mozilla's CSS docs on the `font-size` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Values).

**Example 1**

Here, the `font-size` of the body element is set to 24px.

Adding `xx-large` to a paragraph sets its size *absolutely* to 32px.

Adding `larger` to a paragraph increments the base size set on the body *relatively* to 28.8px.

```css
body { font-size: 24px; }
.xx-large { font-size: xx-large; }
.larger { font-size: larger; }
```

```html
<p>base size</p>
<p class="xx-large">xx-large size</p>
<p class="larger">larger size</p>
```

**Example 2**

If we change the `font-size` of the body element is set to 48px, we can see the difference between these two values.

Adding `xx-large` to a paragraph *still* sets its size *absolutely* to 32px.

However, adding `larger` to a paragraph increments the base size set on the body *relatively* to 57.6px.

```css
body { font-size: 48px; }
.xx-large { font-size: xx-large; }
.larger { font-size: larger; }
```

```html
<p>base size</p>
<p class="xx-large">xx-large size</p>
<p class="larger">larger size</p>
```

Comment: thank you so much!! In the first example, when you applied larger, it jumped from `24px`  to `28.8px` (4.8 difference) and in the second example, it jumped from `48px` to `57.6px` (9.6 difference) how come there is a change in the difference?

Comment: @likegamecraft `larger` multiplies the base by `1.2`